# Is there a more efficient way to reverse a integer number (both positive and negative) in SCALA?

Tags: string, scala, integer, reverse

I am making a program in SCALA that takes a integer number and reverses it. For example, an input of 30 returns an output of 3. This program must also work for negative numbers, For instance, an input of -89 returns an output of -98. Also, if in the reversal the first digit is 0, it should be truncated (30 to 3). This is the code I have written.

```
import io.StdIn._

val twoDigitNumber : Int = takeInput()
println("The reversal is " + reverse(twoDigitNumber))

//define a function name reverse to handle the actual reverse process for -ve and +ve numbers
 def reverse(x: Integer): Integer = {

 //4 possibilities: +ve, 1st digit 0; -ve, 1st digit zero; -ve, 1st digit not zero; +ve, 1st digit not zero
 if (x> 0 && x.toString.reverse.charAt(0) == 0) {
    x.toString.reverse.substring(1).toInt
 } else if (x<0 && x.toString.substring(1).reverse.charAt(0) == 0) {
  ('-' + x.toString.substring(1).reverse.substring(1)).toInt
 } else if (x<0 && x.toString.substring(1).reverse.charAt(0)!= 0) {
  ('-'+ x.toString.substring(1).reverse).toInt
 } else {
  x.toString.reverse.toInt
 }
}

//reads an integer number
def takeInput() : Int ={
 print("Enter a two-digit integer number: ")
 readInt()
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest I found:

```
x.signum * x.abs.toString.reverse.toInt
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be like below considering x is your integer input:

```
val reverseOutput = if (x>0) x.toString.reverse.toInt else -1* ((x * -1).toString.reverse.toInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def reverseANumber(n: Int): Int = {
    def _reverseANumber(i: Int, i1: Int): Int = i match
      case 0 => i1
      case i =>
        val n = i % 10
        val n1 = n * math.pow(10, (((math.log10(i) + 1).toInt) - 1)).toInt
        _reverseANumber(i / 10, i1 + n1)

    _reverseANumber(n, 0)
  }
```

Comment: this solution works only for positive integer range